# std::map of member functions with different args

Tags: c++, boost, functor, c++03

I have a `DeviceSettingsManager` class that looks like:

```
class DeviceSettingsManager
{
    int32_t PropertyA();
    void SetPropertyA(int32_t prop);
    std::string PropertyB();
    void SetPropertyB(std::string prop);

    // about 50 properties go here ...
}
```

and I need to set the properties according to the property string I have. No code looks like that:

```
// Parse property string ("PropertyA = 100, PropertyB = xyz, ...") to key/value pairs

if (key == "PropertyA")
    manager.SetPropertyA(value);
else if (key == "PropertyB")
    manager.SetPropertyB(value);

// 50 more properties ...
```

Isn't very good, right?

The first idea is to store setters in a map:

```
setters_[key](value); // where for example key == "PropertyA" and value = 100
```

But there is a problem: I can't store in a map different functors:

```
typedef boost::function<void(int32_t)> setter_int_t;
typedef boost::function<void(std::string)> setter_string_t;
std::map<std::string, ???> setters_;
```

Of course, I can have two maps (for `int32_t` and for `std::string`). But it doesn't scale well. If I will be forced to add new setter with argument type like `float` or `double` or even `user_defined_class` I will need more maps.

Other way is to use `boost::any` by in this case I will need to `reinterpret_cast` back to the `boost::function` I need, so facing the problem again.

The question: how can I manage such PropertyManagers in a way that prevents writing billion of if-else statements?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the way to do (don't know whether it is the best one):

```
// checks (map.find(...)) omitted for brevity

struct base_type_holder
{
    virtual ~base_type_holder() {};
};

template<typename T>
struct type_holder : base_type_holder
{
    typedef T type;
};

std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<base_type_holder> > types_;

template<typename T>
void RegisterSetterType(const std::string& name)
{
    types_[name].reset(new type_holder<T>);
}

boost::shared_ptr<base_type_holder> GetSetterType(const std::string& name)
{
    return types_[name];
}

template<typename T>
std::map<std::string, boost::function<void(T)> >& SettersMap()
{
    static std::map<std::string, boost::function<void(T)> > settersMap;
    return settersMap;
}

template<typename T, typename H>
void AddSetter(const std::string& name, void (H::*Setter)(T))
{
    static H settingsManager;
    RegisterSetterType<T>(name);

    SettersMap<T>()[name] = boost::bind(Setter, &settingsManager, ::_1);
}

void CallSetter(const std::string& name, const std::string& value)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<base_type_holder> base_type = GetSetterType(name);
    if (dynamic_cast<type_holder<int32_t> *>(base_type.get()))
    {
        SettersMap<int32_t>()[name](atoi(value.c_str()));
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast<type_holder<std::string> *>(base_type.get()))
    {
        SettersMap<std::string>()[name](value);
    }
}

// Now somewhere in .cpp
AddSetter<int32_t, DeviceSettingsManager>("PropertyA", &DeviceSettingsManager::SetPropertyA);
AddSetter<const std::string&, DeviceSettingsManager>("PropertyB", &DeviceSettingsManager::SetPropertyB);

// other...

// later
CallSetter(key, value); // key = "PropertyA", value = "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be just make a map of `<key, parser>`? And pass initial string, position and manager object to the parser.
It is more flexible than bunch of maps, but you still need to fill in map with concrete Parsers.